# What happens if our target network overestimates the value?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl

When we use DDQN, we often use the target network in case our online network overestimates a value, but this doesn't make sense to me, because

1. What happens if our target network is the one that overestimated a value, then we’d keep using that overestimated value
2. Why can't we use both target network for selection and evaluation